# Angular PrimeNG 10 show, not toggle, expandable table row

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, angular-directive

I know how to toggle an expandable table row in PrimeNG with the `pRowToggler` directive.  Works great.

Now I have the need for adding a button to a table row that *only* opens the row, not toggle it.  In other words, one-way only:  click it to open the row.  Click it when the row is open, nothing should happen.

I cannot find a method to open the row, only a `toggleRow` method.  Is this even possible?

Here is there directive, from their github:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[pRowToggler]'
})
export class RowToggler {

    @Input('pRowToggler') data: any;

    @Input() pRowTogglerDisabled: boolean;

    constructor(public dt: Table) { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: Event) {
        if (this.isEnabled()) {
            this.dt.toggleRow(this.data, event);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    isEnabled() {
        return this.pRowTogglerDisabled !== true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I wound up just disabling the pRowToggler while the row is expanded:

```
    <div
        [pRowToggler]="rowData"
        [pRowTogglerDisabled]="expanded"
        [ngClass]=" !expanded ? 'fake-link' : ''"
    >
    Open Me
    </div>
```